# Constant Contact - PHP wrapper for REST API?

Tags: php, email, constantcontact

Anyone written or know of a decent PHP helper class written for Constant Contact's new REST API?

I've looked at their sample application... has a bunch of inline examples... helpful, but I'm thinking I want to either find or write a helper class to fully encapsulate the API so that all one has to do is interact with the PHP object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually just started this project myself. It does almost everything the REST APIs allow. It will probably help you get off the ground with your integration.

http://www.envoymediagroup.com/Code/CTCT-Web-Services-PHP-Library.html

Comment: The link looks like the stylesheet is missing.

Answer (score 0):

They have a PHP sample application:

http://img.constantcontact.com/webservices/samples/PHPSample.zip

Comment: Yeah, I've looked at that... has a bunch of inline examples... helpful, but I'm thinking I want to either find or write a helper class to fully encapsulate the API so that all one has to do is interact with the PHP object.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but I thought it would be helpful to add in the official Constant Contact PHP SDK wrapper: https://github.com/constantcontact/php-sdk

Answer (score 0):

An old thread, but thought people might be interested in a V3 PHP client:

https://packagist.org/packages/phpfui/constantcontact